# proving that the shortest line conntecting a point and a line will be perpendicular to that line

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization

So I have a problem for my final math project that I've been fiddling with for hours without success. I have to use calculus to prove that the shortest line connecting a point to a line will always be perpendicular to the line. Here's what I've got so far

1. Use the distance formula
2. take the derivative of it and set it equal to 0
   now heres where I'm confused.. what do I take it in terms of? I know that I have to use this information to find the slope connecting then line, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the line is non-vertical and has the equation $y=mx+b$, and let the point be $(x_0,y_0)$.
Then the distance from the point to the line is 
$$d=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(mx+b-y_0)^2}.$$

Since the square root is awkward to work with, we minimize $d^2$ instead.

$$f(x)=d^2=(x-x_0)^2+(mx+b,y_0)^2.$$

Now use the usual procedure with critical points and so on to minimize $f$.
Once you find the value of $x$ which minimizes $f$, you can obtain the point on the line which is closest to $(x_0,y_0)$.  Of course, from there you can easily find the slope of the line through $(x_0,y_0)$ and the closest point.

Comment: I feel stupid for asking this but what exactly do I do with x to find the point on the line? or is the point just going to be (y/m)-b?

Comment: Do you know how to find the critical points of a function?

Comment: yeah, take the derivative of the funciton and set it equal to zero. I know how to get x, I've already solved it for x, but I can't figure out what to do with that x to find the corresponding y

Comment: The point will be $(x,mx+b)$.

Comment: and then you just use the slope formula to get the slope of the line connecting the two and compare it to the slope of the line?

Comment: Yes that correct.

Comment: Hi! I noticed there is a comma on the second (mx+b,y0) isn't there supposed to be a minus sign?